# Yii2 Jquery code inside <script> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2

My problem is that I wrote a lot of code inside `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` tags and most of this code is Jquery code and initially this works because it was referenced to a remote source:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

But the thing is that it can't depend on internet, so I need all this code working locally and I can't adjust all those lines to `$this->registerJs("");` It's just endless work.

So how can I make all this code inside `<script></script>` tags works locally with Jquery?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your script into a js file inside your project, and register it like follows:

```
$this->registerJsFile('@web/js/myCustomJs.js', [
    'depends' => [\yii\web\JqueryAsset::className()]
]);
```

So you don't need to juggle with single and double quotes trying to make it work with `$this->registerJs("");`.

Note: on the example code `depends` makes it so your js file loads after Jquery.

Comment: Thank you so much!!